# Requisição curl POSt com PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Como faço a seguinte requisição em PHP?

```
curl -X POST "http://api.urlapi.com.br" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"menssage\": \"Aqui envio a mensagem\", \"number\": \"55123456789\"}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando a própria biblioteca de CURL seria assim:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.urlapi.com.br');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"menssage\": \"Aqui envio a mensagem\", \"number\": \"55123456789\"}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Porem recomendo você usar a biblioteca Guzzle, ela é a umas das mais usadas para fazer requests, a documentação é bem explicada: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: Valeu, obrigado!